# How can filter through 100K records in indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I have a IndexedDB store that has 100k fields of names. 
How To filter it based on name includes some substring?

I tried to use indexeddb getall() but resulted in increased CPU usage.
Using Cursor to iterate took a lot of time.
Tried dexie js.

Is there any good implementation to do this kind of operation?

Comment: Did you index the name field? An indexed `filter()` using dexie should work well

Answer (score 1):

If you index the name field, you can do a prefix search, but ordinary indexes are not enough for full substring searches.

```
const db = new Dexie ('dbname');
db.version(1).stores({things: 'id, name'});

function query(prefix) {
  return db.things
    .where('name').startsWith(prefix)
    .toArray();
}
```

This sample defines an index on the 'name' field and the query function will do getAll() on the 'name' index using an IDBKeyRange representing all names that starts with the given string.